# Significance of the parameter fitdf in Box.test

Tags: r, time-series, arima, residuals, degrees-of-freedom

When reading `?Box.test`, I learned about a rarely mentioned parameter `fitdf`, which specified the "number of degrees of freedom to be subtracted if x is a series of residuals". It seems that when applying this function on residuals, we should pass this parameter to `Box.test`.

> #### Details
>
> These tests are sometimes applied to the residuals from an `ARMA(p, q)`
>   fit, in which case the references suggest a better approximation to
>   the null-hypothesis distribution is obtained by setting `fitdf = p+q`,
>   provided of course that `lag > fitdf`.

However, many appear to ignore this suggestion. Here is the source code of an implementation of the S3 method `tsdiag`. Note that `Box.test` didn't get `fitdf`.

```
> getS3method("tsdiag", "Arima")
function (object, gof.lag = 10, ...) 
{
    oldpar <- par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
    on.exit(par(oldpar))
    rs <- object$residuals
    stdres <- rs/sqrt(object$sigma2)
    plot(stdres, type = "h", main = "Standardized Residuals", 
        ylab = "")
    abline(h = 0)
    acf(object$residuals, plot = TRUE, main = "ACF of Residuals", 
        na.action = na.pass)
    nlag <- gof.lag
    pval <- numeric(nlag)
    for (i in 1L:nlag) pval[i] <- Box.test(rs, i, type = "Ljung-Box")$p.value
    plot(1L:nlag, pval, xlab = "lag", ylab = "p value", ylim = c(0, 
        1), main = "p values for Ljung-Box statistic")
    abline(h = 0.05, lty = 2, col = "blue")
}
<bytecode: 0x7fad483ad6c8>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Is this OK?

Comment: This is not OK. See my comments under the answer of javlacalle in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/) and my answer in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136116/).